# how to display exception response text

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, ex

I have the following function, I am trying to display the response text that comes back from the ex.responseText. how ever every time I try it comes back as "undefined" but the text is actually there

```
onError: function (ex) {


            $('<div>' + ex._message + '</div>').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: "Items",
                buttons: { "Okay": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
            });
        }
```

so I tried the following

```
$('<div>' + ex.responseText + '</div>').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Items",
                    buttons: { "Okay": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                });
```

and it shows me the error like this `{"message":"You have entered duplicate items. Please remove."}`

I just want it to show the actual message `You have entered duplicate items. Please remove.` and not show the {} brackets and "message" text.

I also tried

```
 var message = JSON.parse(ex.responseText)._message;
 $('<div>' + message + '</div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Items",
            buttons: { "Okay": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
        });
```

and it still comes back as undefined.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ex.responseText.message, since the error message is an object you need to target the key.

To put it more clear:

```js
ex.responseText = {
    "message": "You have entered duplicate items. Please remove."
}

ex.responseText.message = "You have entered duplicate items. Please remove.";
```

Comment: this doesnt work,it still comes back as "undefined"

Comment: @marry The alternative is:
JSON.parse(ex.responseText).message

This should work.

Comment: Reason being if it shows it as {message:"sjndjas"} it means the JSON is stringified. It should be parse to be mapped as an object.

Comment: thank you!!! so long i was trying " var message = JSON.parse(ex.responseText)._message;" and i didnt notice it should be "message" and not "_message". was driving me insane.